# Arrays na clausula 'NOT IN' WHERE

Tags: oracle, pl-sql

```
DECLARE 
   string_valor  VARCHAR2(100);
   lista_array dbms_utility.lname_array;
   contador binary_integer; 
BEGIN 
   SELECT t.campo_a INTO string_valor
   FROM tabela t
   WHERE t.campo_cod = 1;
   dbms_utility.comma_to_table
   (
       list          => regexp_replace(string_valor,'(^|,)','\1x')
       , tablen  => contador
       , tab       => lista_array
   );       
   FOR i in 1 .. l_count LOOP
      dbms_output.put_line( substr(lista_array(i),2) );
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Esse codigo funciona perfeitamente, o que ele faz é pegar uma variavel VARCHAR com valores '2,3,5,9' por exemplo e separa-los em um vetor de números, para que essa necessidade? Para que eu possa comparar, utilizando NOT IN, cada elemento do ARRAY com um campo de NUMBER dentro da clausula WHERE.

O problema é como posso chama-lo na clausula Where, utilizando o NOT IN:

```
SELECT ... FROM tabela t
WHERE campo_exemplo_1 > 0 
      AND campo_exemplo_2 <> campo_exemplo_4
      AND campo_exemplo_3 NOT IN ( ARRAY AQUI??? )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vasculhando o velho o google e juntando informações, consegui resolver o problema, vou deixar postado aqui o resultado caso alguém necessite.

```
DECLARE 
    V_varchar2  VARCHAR2(100);
    l_List_char dbms_utility.lname_array;
    l_count binary_integer;   

    TYPE TesteVarchar2 IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
    l_Aux_ListNumber TesteVarchar2  := TesteVarchar2();
    resultado NUMBER;

BEGIN      
    V_varchar2 := '2,9,8,10,5';
    dbms_utility.comma_to_table
    (
         list      => regexp_replace(V_varchar2,'(^|,)','\1x')
         , tablen  => l_count
         , tab     => l_List_char
    ); 

    l_Aux_ListNumber.EXTEND(l_count);

    FOR i in 1 .. l_count LOOP       
         l_Aux_ListNumber(i) := substr(l_List_char(i),2);
    END LOOP;

    -- Aqui uma pequena operação matematica para provar que virou number
    FOR i in 1 .. l_count LOOP
         dbms_output.put_line( l_Aux_ListNumber(i));
         resultado := l_Aux_ListNumber(i) * i;
         dbms_output.put_line( 'Result: ' || resultado );   
    END LOOP;

END;
```

Ai só chamar dentro clausula:

```
Where na clausula NOT IN ( SELECT column_value FROM TABLE( TesteVarchar2() );
```

Answer (score 2):

A cláusula `NOT IN` deve ser preenchida com os valores que você quer pesquisar no campo.

Por exemplo, se o campo é uma chave estrangeira, faça uma subquery selecionando apenas os `id`s da tabela.

Tabela post

```
id titulo
 1 Titulo do post 1
 2 Titulo do post 2
```

Tabela category

```
id titulo
 1 Curiosidades
 2 Bobagens
 3 Variedades
```

Tabela post_category

```
post_id category_id
      1           1
      1           3
      2           2
      2           3
```

Sua query, então, ficaria assim:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM post p
INNER JOIN post_category pc
    ON pc.post_id = p.id
    AND pc.category_id IN (
        SELECT c.id
        FROM category c
        WHERE c.titulo = 'Variedades'
    )
```

PS: baseei minha resposta no padrão do ANSI SQL. Talvez o Oracle possua algumas diferenças na implementação do `IN` mas acho improvável.

Comment: Agradeço, porem essa foi a primeira solução que vem na mente, contudo o select e muito complexo e tem vários OR dentro do Where, neste caso todos eles iram ter que fazer o mesmo subselect, por isso parti para o ARRAY.